# Arduino - Not able to burn the sketches

Tags: arduino

I am new to the Arduino world. Finding a strange issue with when I try to upload the sketches in Arduino IDE. It is giving me the following error:

```
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.

avrdude: stk500v2_command(): unknown status 0x01
avrdude: stk500v2_disable(): failed to leave programming mode
```

I am getting this error in both Duemilanove as well as Mega 2560.

However, when I burn the bootloader using the programmer, and then try to upload the sketch, it works for the first time. If I try to upload the same sketch again, it throws the error mentioned above.

Comment: My guess is that your bootloader is broken somehow. Find the official bootloaders for your devices in the Arduino project and re-burn them.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for the quick response. I used the bootloader that are shipped with the Arduino IDE. I had tried with the bootloaders that came with Arduino 0021, Arduino 0019 and the latest Arduino-1.0.

Comment: Try arduino0023 if you can. I recall having a problem with 1.0 bootloader on my uno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by changing the fuse settings. After I changed my fuse settings, I am now able to burn the sketches any number of times.

Answer (score 0):

I would try re-installing the arduino IDE as it could have gotten corrupted or outdated. Check to see if you have the right model and serial port selected on the menu. Also get on arduino's website ([arduino.cc](http://arduino.cc)) and there should be a contact link.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by changing the fuse settings. After I changed my fuse settings, I am now able to burn the sketches any number of times.

Answer (score 0):

I remember I had this issue. So basically it is saying that Arduino is not connectted (even though it physically might be connected). Basically make sure the computer sees the Arduino so make sure your COM port detects an Arduino and the drivers installed correctly. For me, it was plugged into the USB port, BUT it first went through a USB Hub (so basically Arduino -> USB Hub -> Computer). The way I solved it was by plugging the Arduino directly into the Computer such that it goes Arduino -> Computer.